# Control for a variable in regression (Python)

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to perform multiple linear regression using statsmodels while controlling for one variable but I am not sure how to control for a variable in python.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results = smf.ols('y ~ Var1 + Var2', data=df).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

How can I control for Var2 on this example? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "controlling" a variable?

Comment: Including a variable in a regression that is not directly of interest is what controlling means.  For example, if  you are interested in the relationship between y and x controlling for z1 and z2, you would have `"y ~ 1 + x + z1 + z2"`.  If there is a relationship between y and x in this model then you know it isn't because y is caused by z1 and x is caused by z1 and you left z1 out.